# @Async not working for me

Tags: java, spring

I am using @Scheduled and it have been working fine, but can't get the @Async working. I tested it many times, and seems that it is making my method asynchronous. Is there any other thing, configuration, or parameter I am missing? I have one class that has two methods one, the method marked with @Scheduled, executes and calls the second one which has been marked with @Async.

Here is my config:

```xml
<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.socialmeety" />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<task:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Configures support for @Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<dwr:configuration />
<dwr:annotation-config />
<dwr:url-mapping />
<dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should provide some more info. (code snippets etc)

Comment: don't have any exception it just doesn't make the method asynchronous. Any especial configuration to get it working? that is my question, will post my config to tell more about my env. I already have my @Scheduled working fine.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As you're calling your @Async method from another method in the same object, you're probably bypassing the async proxy code and just calling your plain method, ie within the same thread.

One way of solving this is by making sure your call to the @Async method is from another object.  See comments at end of this article:
http://groovyjavathoughts.blogspot.com/2010/01/asynchronous-code-with-spring-3-simple.html

But it gets messy doing things like that, so you could just autowire the TaskScheduler, wrap up your method in a Runnable and execute it yourself.

Comment: Certainly an easy thing to miss.

Answer (score 4):

This is a complementary answer to the accepted one.  You can call an async method in your own class, but you have to create a self-referential bean.

The only side-effect here is that you **cannot** call any async code inside the constructor.  It is a nice way to keep your code all in the same place.

```
@Autowired ApplicationContext appContext;
private MyAutowiredService self;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    self = appContext.getBean(MyAutowiredService.class);
}

public void doService() {
    //This will invoke the async proxy code
    self.doAsync();
}

@Async 
public void doAsync() {
    //Async logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem similar to this. And I spent a lot of time to fix it.

If you use **spring-context 3.2**, you also need to add **@EnableAsync** on the class where you call the method service annotated **@Async**

Take a look at http://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/#initial

I hope that it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@EnableAsync` in your service...

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding some details to the solution you provide?

Comment: @alireza alallah :  Please add some details to the answer