# @Async in Spring doesn't work in Service class?

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-boot

`@Async` method in `@Service` annotated class in standalone Spring Boot application doesn't run asynchronously. What am I doing wrong?

When I run the same method directly from main class (`@SpringBootApplication` annotated), it works. Example:

**Main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // here when I call downloadAnSave() it runs asynchronously...
        // but when I call downloadAnSave() via downloadAllImages() it does not run asynchronously...
    }

}
```

and my **service class** (and here asynchronous behavior doesn't work):

```
@EnableAsync
@Service
public class ImageProcessorService implements IIMageProcessorService {

    public void downloadAllImages(Run lastRun) {
        // this method calls downloadAnSave() in loop and should run asynchronously....
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    public boolean downloadAnSave(String productId, String imageUrl) {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot @Async method in controller is executing synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284008/spring-boot-async-method-in-controller-is-executing-synchronously)

Comment: The question itself does not seem to be an exact duplicate, but the same answer (and comments) apply here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Calling async method from within the same class would trigger the original method and not the intercepted one. 
You need to create another service  with the async method, and call it from your service.

Spring creates a proxy for each service and component you create using the common annotations. Only those proxies contain the wanted behavior defined by the method annotations such as the Async. So, calling those method not via the proxy but by the original naked class would not trigger those behaviors.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. For clarification and my information, please can you explain what you mean with "would trigger the original method and not the intercepted one"? Thanks.

Comment: You can also self-inject and it would work, but I don't think it's advised, as it usually breaks the Single Responsibility Principle

Comment: Can you explain why self-inject breaks "Single Responsibility Principle"?

Comment: Thanks a lot. working perfectly in another service

Answer (score 3):

Workaround is:

```
@EnableAsync
@Service("ip-service")
public class ImageProcessorService implements IIMageProcessorService {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ip-service")
    ImageProcessorService ipService;

    public void downloadAllImages(Run lastRun) {
        // this method calls downloadAnSave() in loop and should run asynchronously....
        ipService.downloadAnSave(productId, imageUrl);
    }

    @Async
    @Override
    public boolean downloadAnSave(String productId, String imageUrl) {
        //
    }
}
```

With such approach you call method of proxy, not the class instance.
The same approach can be used with other tools working with proxies, e.g. @Transactional etc.

Comment: It doesn't work in latest Springboot version, and says: "Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default."

Comment: You can avoid this error by adding @ Lazy to the @ Autowired property.